# Swap 2-character block with the next one in a list

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to implement an algorithm in Python that swaps a 2-character block with the next 2-character block for every block of 4 characters, for example if I have "2d14 56f2" it will be "142d f256". Can someone help me out please? Here's what I've worked on so far but it doesn't work...

```
        def swap_bits(data):
            data = list(data)
            for x,y in zip(data[::2], data[1::2]):
                
                
                for i in range(0, len(data)-1, 4):
                    x, y = y, x

            return ''.join(data)
```

Here's the string I wish to swap: "2d14541501158000000000001e000000190000000000030003000300030000200800e01e7c580000d462866058040908018f1d196d0ed5628660f60801001900fc1e"

So it should be 142d15541501... It takes every 4-character blocks and swaps their content in pairs of characters.

Comment: Please provide more detail than "it doesn't work".

Comment: `x, y = y, x` This just swaps those variables.  It does not update the original lists that the values came from.

Comment: What if `data`'s length isn't a multiple of 4?

Comment: @ScottHunter It literally does nothing to the string. I have a long string that is: "2d14541501158000000000001e000000190000000000030003000300030000200800e01e7c580000d462866058040908018f1d196d0ed5628660f60801001900fc1e"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the OP's source data has a space in it (based on later edits). Therefore:

```
s = "2d14541501158000000000001e000000190000000000030003000300030000200800e01e7c580000d462866058040908018f1d196d0ed5628660f60801001900fc1e"

def swap(s):
    assert len(s) % 4 == 0
    result = []
    for i in range(0, len(s), 4):
        result.append(s[i+2:i+4])
        result.append(s[i:i+2])
    return ''.join(result)

print(swap(s))
```

**Output:**

```
142d15541501008000000000001e00000019000000000003000300030003200000081ee0587c000062d46086045808098f01191d0e6d62d5608608f6000100191efc
```

Answer (score 0):

check if you can use this :

```
string = '2d14 56f2'
str_list = string.split(' ')
empty_list = []

for word in str_list:
    new_word = word[2:] + word[:2]
    empty_list.append(new_word)
    
print(' '.join(empty_list))
```

Comment: `empty_list.append(empty_list)`?! Did you mean `empty_list.append(new_word)`?

Comment: yes i got distracted for a second

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
def swap(s):
    blocks = [s[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(s), 4)]
    for i in range(len(blocks)):
        blocks[i] = blocks[i][2:] + blocks[i][:2]
    return "".join(blocks)

print(swap("2d1456f2"))
```

Output:

```
142df256
```

with string `2d14541501158000000000001e000000190000000000030003000300030000200800e01e7c580000d462866058040908018f1d196d0ed5628660f60801001900fc1e`

```
print(swap("2d14541501158000000000001e000000190000000000030003000300030000200800e01e7c580000d462866058040908018f1d196d0ed5628660f60801001900fc1e"))
```

Output:

```
142d15541501008000000000001e00000019000000000003000300030003200000081ee0587c000062d46086045808098f01191d0e6d62d5608608f6000100191efc
```

Comment: When I apply it to the long string which is: "2d14541501158000000000001e000000190000000000030003000300030000200800e01e7c580000d462866058040908018f1d196d0ed5628660f60801001900fc1e" it just places 2d at the end of that string just like the above solution..

Comment: I thought the blocks are seperated by spaces?!